# Align stars in multiple images

Tags: image-processing, astronomy, alignment

I hope that you find this question interesting and that this will help others with similar problems as this configuration is not so particular.

#### My problem

I have multiple images of a particular region in the sky. These images depict stars. In order to make measures i have to align the images first (to identify the same star in each image, for example). I'm finding this task extreamly difficult. This is what i have tried so far:

- First I tried to use `ImageAlign` with the two images, but it did not work. As the correction should be a translation, I also tried to giving `TransformationClass -> "Translation"` as an option, but that did not work.
- The best approach so far is the following:
- Binarize the images to show the stars more clearly.
- Identify the stars using `MorphologicalComponents`.
- Use `FindGeometricTransormation` with the coordinates of the stars to find a transformation using the option `TransformationClass -> "Translation".

This last approach work iff the images are very closely related.

Here is the link of the actual images and a binarize copy of them:

http://s28.postimg.org/mk78gibi3/Image1.png

http://s28.postimg.org/x5r3sihtn/Image2.png

http://s28.postimg(dot)org/o86dv5pdp/Binarize1.png

http://s28.postimg(dot)org/x4h5z3fzx/Binarize2.png

As the final objective is to automate the process, the less human input to the process the better.

Comment: I have tried this before and I didn't find it very easy in *Mathematica*. My suggestion would be to use some specialized software like [DeepSkyStacker](http://deepskystacker.free.fr/english/index.html), where someone has already figured out the details for you.

Comment: Please post the images in this format: `img1 = Import[
   "https://www.dropbox.com/s/83hyoz5g62rxiut/Image1.png"];
img2 = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/fh25kcmuaij3sus/Image2.png"];` Your current URLs do not work.

Comment: I have updated the question with direct links.

Comment: As Oleksandr says, if you're doing this for more than a mathematica experiment, you'll do far better using COTS software. I use something called registar, quite effective...

Comment: I use [http://nova.astrometry.net](http://nova.astrometry.net/), an online service.

Comment: I have checked the software you mention but it fails to find the alignment. Also, i appreciate all your suggestions, but i really want to use Mathematica.

Comment: @PabloGalindoSalgado: Understood re: use of Mathematica. There are some wizards here with the image processing goodies, I hope one sees the question and takes a swing at it. +1 and favorite, most interesting question...

Comment: Could you describe more precisely what is input output? You just want `myAlign[pic1, pic2] -> mergedPics` without any additional help from user? should in work on more than two images at once? could you provide more is so?

Comment: @Kuba Yup. The input should be a collection of images {img1,img2,img3...etc} and a reference one (for example img1) and the output should be one of the following:

-The TransformationFunction between the pixels of the reference image and the rest of the collection as FindGeometricTransform does.

-A new collection of images in which every one is aligned with the reference image, as ImageAlign does, that is, if the coordinates of a star in the reference image are (x0,y0), these are also the coordinates of the SAME star in the collection frames.

All with the minumum interaction possible.

Comment: I have no problems with getting the images but I will post them in the question later.

Comment: Note that in the last 2 images you must substitute (dot) with a . in order to work. (This is because the restrictions in the site when posting links).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATED VERSION:**

Import the images:

```
img1 = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "Image1.png"];
img2 = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "Image2.png"];
imgs = {img1, img2};
ImageCollage[imgs]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Binarize the two images using the "MinimumError"-Method, pad the images (hald the size of the original images) and perform an Opening to get rid of binarized background noise:

```
imgsbin = Opening[ImagePad[Binarize[#, FindThreshold[#, Method -> "MinimumError"]], 512], 1] & /@ imgs;
ImageCollage[imgsbin]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Dilate the binarized stars (original stars are obviously too small for ImageAlign to find an appropriate transformation, 20 seems to work well):

```
imgsbindil = Dilation[#, 20] & /@ imgsbin;
ImageCollage[imgsbindil]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Align the images:

```
imgal = ImageAlign[imgsbindil[[1]], imgsbindil[[2]], TransformationClass -> "Rigid", Method -> "Keypoints"];
ColorCombine[{imgsbindil[[1]], imgal}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Erode the images back to normal object size:

```
ColorCombine[{Erosion[imgsbindil[[1]], 20], Erosion[imgal, 20]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Binarize the result:

```
% // Binarize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The method works quite well for the provided images, but the result depends on the image quality. This mainly affects stars that are cut by the image border (objects do not overlap properly, see bottom left in the final image).

Comment: The solution is great, but for some reason, ImageAlign[] sometimes fails (not for these images) even when you use TransformationClass->"Translation".

Comment: @Kardeshev3 Here you have two images in which ImageAlign[] fails. Do you know the reason?

http://s4.postimg.org/qes23r9nv/image.png
http://s17.postimg.org/6ndsk6z8t/image.png

Comment: I edited the proposed approach to cope with the new provided images. The trick is to dilate the binarized images prior to alignment, since ImageAling obviously needs bigger objects to find an appropriate transformation.

Answer (score 4):

Those listed below might more like a suggestion than an answer with a lot of handwork.

First import the img downloaded from your link.

```
img1 = Import@"D:\\...\\lteiaq94pImage2.png"; 
img2 = Import@"D:\\...\\peadtydo9Image1.png";
```

Binarize them with carefully chosed parameters:

```
img1bin = Erosion[Binarize[img1, 0.2], 0.4];
img2bin = Erosion[Binarize[img2, 0.4], 0.5];
```

img1bin and img2bin look like:

[image: img1bin enter image description here]

and

[image]

get ImageData:

```
img1bind = ImageData@img1bin; img2bind = ImageData@img2bin;
```

chose a sample for align:

```
Image@img2bind[[500 ;; -1, 1 ;; 500]]
```

which looks like:

[image]

define the coincide function:

```
data2 = img2bind[[500 ;; -1, 1 ;; 500]];
coincide[x_, y_] := 
Total[data2*img1bind[[500 - y ;; -1 - y, 1 + x ;; 500 + x]], 2]
```

search for the "most likely coincide area":

```
posi = Outer[coincide, Range[1, 450, 10], Range[1, 450, 10]]
```

find the position related to the "most likely coincide area":

```
Position[posi, Max[posi]]
```

which returned {{23, 15}}, define

```
img1cut[x_, y_] := 
Image[img1bind[[500 - y ;; -1 - y, 1 + x ;; 500 + x]]];
```

then we see

```
img1cut[231, 151]
```

gives the almost same four stars in sample:

[image]

you can refine the search grid(*which is 10*) at neighborhood of {231, 151} for more accurate result.

Comment: Pablo, Have yu done some treatment before stacking images, as dark, flat and bias?

Comment: Yes, the images are reduced with a masterdark and a masterflat.

Comment: This is a very nice approach, but there are some problems. For example, using the coincide function, sometimes the convolution (the product) of a big star of the general image with one of the stars in the reference image gives a maximum bigger than the correct one. As we want this process to be automatic, specify the region is not desirable.

Comment: Probably, more reference star would help. Could you use a FOV bigger?

Comment: larger sample or larger field of view might be obtain by  take larger sample with similar code. such as replace `img2bind[[500 ;; -1, 1 ;; 500]];` to`img2bind[[400 ;; -1, 1 ;; 600]];` or more. but avoid the left top white noise area.

Comment: @Harry , you are right, but in a general case i do not know the location and/or structure of noise areas. I hope that there is some approach using a combination of Morphological Components, ImageAlign, FindGeometricTransform...
For example:

-Using FindMorphologicalComponents i can identify the coordinates of the stars in each frame. (To achieve this i binarize first the images using a threshold 4*StandarDeviation over the background noise, which works very well).
The problem is how relate the coordinates of the stars in each frame.I tried FindGeometricTransform helps, but I cannot do it work.